# Meteor: Signin with linkedin not recognizing existing users

Tags: meteor, linkedin-api, meteor-accounts

In my meteor application I am using the packages accounts-linkedin and linkedin to allow my users to signin with linkedin. This has always been working fine for several month. However, since yesterday users who have signed in to my website via linkedin in the past are not recognized anymore. When they go to "login with linkedin" a new meteor user account is created for them instead of logging them into their existing account.
When I test my application: Signing up via linkedin und then logging out and in, everything is working fine. Apparently it is only not working for accounts that already existed a few days ago.
This is really strange. The accounts code of meteor is really complex. What could be the reason that a user is not recognized anymore but a new user account gets created for them?
Could it be that linkedin messed up tokens on their side? (the linkedin id and accessToken in my users object (services.linkedin) did not change over the last days)

Comment: I realized that all existing users have really short services.linkedin.id : It is only numbers and only around max 10 numbers long. But when I do a new login with linkedin now, the services.linkedin.id is a very long made out of numbers and letters. Could that be a reason?

Comment: There are several linkedin packages. It looks like `pauli:accounts-linkedin` is the most popular. Is that the one you are using? Also, what versions of that package and the `linkedin` package are you using, and did you update either of them or Meteor itself recently?

Comment: `pauli:linkedin` extracts the id from the query parameter of the user's `siteStandardProfileRequest.url` which is part of the data returned by an authenticated call to `https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~`. Another part of that data is an `id` field. When I just tested this for my own account, I get different values for the 2 ids. The query param is long and the field is 10 characters (including some letters). I'm not sure why pauli is using the query param. Perhaps they used to be the same, but LinkedIn changed the query param recently?

Comment: I use the pauli:accounts-linkedin package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug in `pauli:accounts-linkedin`](https://github.com/PauliBuccini/meteor-accounts-linkedin/issues/14). The `pauli:linkedin` package was using the wrong value for the user's LinkedIn ID. I have submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/PauliBuccini/meteor-linkedin/pull/8) which fixes that problem for new users, but a fix is still needed to migrate the IDs of existing users. I recommend subscribing to the bug to track progress.

Comment: That looks very promising. I will test it, especially the migration of the existing users and then mark this solved if it works. Thanks.